# Consulta sql a base de datos de expedientes

Tags: mysql, php5

Estoy teniendo problemas con una consulta a una base de datos, no se si lo que hice es correcto o hay otra forma de realizarla. La idea es que consulte si hay expedientes para un profesional x pero que este no sea de la categoría xx y que tampoco este null.

aquí el código

```
$query= "
SELECT * 
FROM 
expedientes
WHERE profesional_dni= $dni AND tarea_desc != 'INFORME PERICIAL' OR tarea_desc IS NULL
ORDER BY fecha Desc";
```

Muchas Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Primeramente el estándar para *no es igual a* es `<>`, no `!=`, en segundo lugar, si quieres filtrar los que no son nulos, deberías usar `IS NOT NULL`. Luego, como ha sugerido Tomás en su respuesta, conviene que uses los paréntesis para agrupar los criterios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero utilizar paréntesis cuando apliques varios condicionales mixtos `or` y `and` en una consulta SQL dado que las condiciones de la consulta se pueden cumplir en un orden que no sea el requerido. Quizá esta sea tu solución:

```
SELECT * 

FROM 
    expedientes

WHERE 
    profesional_dni= $dni 
    AND ( tarea_desc != 'INFORME PERICIAL' OR tarea_desc IS NULL )

ORDER BY fecha DESC
```